# Edit the transferred Object (using Property transfer) in SOAPUI

Tags: json, api, soapui, web-api-testing

I have the following test steps:

- GetDetails
- transferObject (Property transfer)
- Change Details

GetDetails outputs a JSON object as follows:

```json
{
   "databaseId": 123,
   "databaseName": "Test",
   "address": "ON",
   "details":    {
        "detail_id": 999,
        "userId": 2,
        "date": null,
        "state": "active"
    },
   "itemName": "Bob details",
}
```

**transferObject** transfers this `details` object to **ChangeDetails** test step.

But now I want to modify the object (*change the `state` property to `non-active`*) before feeding it to ChangeDetails test case.

How can I do that? any suggestions?

Comment: What you mentioned seems to be `test steps` of a test case, correct? More over, it appears that there are multiple `details` and not unique, so little more json snippet needed to explain it. By the you can use `Property Expansion` for the same.

Comment: @Rao: You are right! I've edited my post. In a single JSON object `details` property is unique. Where can I find the `Property Expansion` ?

Comment: So you want the above data as input to `ChangeDetails` test step? And only change state? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want just the `details` property as input to `ChangeDetails` test step. But before handing it to `ChangeDetails` I want to change the `details.state` to be `inactive`. So following should be the input `"details":    {
        "detail_id": 999,
        "userId": 2,
        "date": null,
        "state": "inactive"
    },`

Comment: [@CodeJockey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1530073/codejockey), please check out the and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure how to achieve this using property transfer step as it appears to be data manipulation.

If it would be achieved, I would do this in the below fashion(Using script assertion) .

Have only two steps

- Get Details
- Change Details

Add a `Script Assertion` with the below code for Get Details step:

```groovy
import groovy.json.*

//Read the response of GetDetails and filter details
def details = new JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response).details

//assert there is details available and not empty
assert details, "Details is empty or null in the response"

//Creating object to build the next step request
def json = new JsonBuilder()

//Building details object for Change
json.details {

  //looping thru each data
    details.each { key, value ->

      //Change state to inactive
      if ('state' == key) value = 'non-active'

      //add the properties inside details
      "$key"("$value")
    }
}

//Create a pretty print sting and this is going to be the next test step's request
def prettyJson = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString())

//Assign this data to a test step custom property, say REQUEST
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('REQUEST', prettyJson)
```

In the Change Details step, open request editor => have `${#TestCase#REQUEST}`

Now run your test see if it is working as you needed.

Note: It is mentioned in the comment `inactive`, but it is mentioned in the question to be `non-active` - so kept the same in the reply. I think it is not really big deal in this case, I believe.

Comment: Thanks @Rao. That Worked!